# Is it possible to set a PHPDoc to "reference" a class variable?

Tags: phpdoc

I have Repository classes that descend from a common class `BaseRepository` which has a method `findAll()`.  This will return an Entity class which descends from a `BaseEntity`.

The `@return` on the the `BaseRepository::findAll()` is currently `BaseEntity[]` but it really returns the specific Entity appropriate for that Repository.  In each Repository class there is a class constant `ENTITY_CLASS` which tells the internals which class to instantiate has the class name it returns.

I can add a PHPDoc to each Repository `@method FooEntity[] findAll()` but there are many.  Is it possible to somehow have the return of `findAll()` be something like:

`@return static::ENTITY_CLASS[] findAll()`

I tried it and it didn't work.  Is there a way to do this?  We're using PHPStorm so if there is a hack that will work for this IDE, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. Adding `@method FooEntity[] findAll()` to your child class is the way to go.